# Apache mod_disk_cache on a seperate drive

Tags: apache-2.2

how can I set Apache mod_disk_cache on a separate drive from where the OS/Apache is installed?

I have set up this on my apache2.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_cache_disk.c>

    # cache cleaning is done by htcacheclean, which can be configured in
    # /etc/default/apache2
    #
    # For further information, see the comments in that file,
    # /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian, and the htcacheclean(8)
    # man page.

    # This path must be the same as the one in /etc/default/apache2
    CacheRoot /media/cacheHD

    # This will also cache local documents. It usually makes more sense to
    # put this into the configuration for just one virtual host.
    CacheEnable disk /


    # The result of CacheDirLevels * CacheDirLength must not be higher than
    # 20. Moreover, pay attention on file system limits. Some file systems
    # do not support more than a certain number of inodes and
    # subdirectories (e.g. 32000 for ext3)
    CacheDirLevels 2
    CacheDirLength 1

</IfModule>
```

and it doesn't seem to be caching anything at all. The drive itself is a freshly installed ssd drive formatted with ext4.

Answer (score 0):

The module [`mod_cache`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_cache.html) itself must be loaded before you load the [`disk storage manager module`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_disk_cache.html) and as always modules must loaded before you can try to configure them.

You can confirm if all the correct modules get loaded with:

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
```

Maybe you copied an incomplete config but the following is more complete:

```
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
<IfModule mod_cache.c>
   # If you want to use mod_disk_cache :
   LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so

   <IfModule mod_cache_disk.c>
      # settings for mod_disk_cache 
      CacheRoot /media/cacheHD
      CacheEnable disk /
      CacheDirLevels 2
      CacheDirLength 1
   </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have found the solution to the problem. I have checked the module and they are installed and on my system (ubuntu/apache2) it doesn't seem there is need to nest modules even if one is dependent on the other. The problem was that my cache drive needed to be mounted inside my apache2 root folder (so in my case, inside /var/www/html) and it needed to have the proper permission instead of root, in my case it was "sudo chown www-data:root <folder_name>". Thanks again for your help.